# stoi and stoll in c++

Tags: c++, string, compilation, string.h

I have #include(string) in my declaratives at the top of the program but when I try to run stoi(string) or stoll(string) i get the following error. I am running Cygwin g++ v4.5.3.

> Z:\G\CSCE 437>g++ convert.cpp -o conv
>   convert.cpp: In function `void transfer(std::string*)':
>   convert.cpp:103:36: error:`stoll' was not declared in this scope
>   convert.cpp:116:35: error: `stoi' was not declared in this scope

```
    fileTime[numRec] = stoll(result[0]);    //converts string to Long Long
    if(numRec = 0){
       beginningTime = fileTime[0];
    }
    fileTime[numRec] = timeDiff;
    hostName[numRec] = result[1];
    diskNum[numRec] = stoi(result[2]);
    type[numRec] = result[3];
    offset[numRec] = stoi(result[4]);
    fileSize[numRec] = stoi(result[5]);
    responseTime[numRec] = stoi(result[6]);`
```

Where result is an array of strings.

Comment: Are you using a C++11-compliant compiler?  Did you include `<string>`?  Are you either using `using namespace std;` or explicitly-qualifying the call as `std::stoll`?

Comment: are you using std::string or char*?

Comment: i am including the string.h file as well as namespace std;

Comment: changed just to string, no change.

Comment: @theB3RV, It could be that they aren't enabled. I had to go in (this is with MinGW) and uncomment the `sto_` and `to_string` parts, and even then, you can only do it with the narrow versions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These functions are new in C++11, and GCC only makes it available if you specify that version of the language using the command-line option `-std=c++11` (or `-std=c++0x` on some older versions; I think you'll need that for version 4.5).

If you can't use C++11 for some reason, you could convert using string streams:

```
#include <sstream>

template <typename T> from_string(std::string const & s) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    T result;
    ss >> result;    // TODO handle errors
    return result;
}
```

or, if you're feeling masochistic, the C functions in such as `strtoll` declared in `<cstring>`.

Comment: I think -std=c++11 was in 4.7.1 or something.

Comment: @chris: Yes, that certainly works for 4.7 and 4.6, and not for 4.4, but I'm not sure about 4.5.

Comment: 4.6.3 doesn't recognize it, as per LWS.

Comment: @chris: OK, I misremembered the state of 4.6. So it sounds like `you need `0x` for 4.5.

Comment: any other ways to convert from string to int or string to long long?

Comment: @theB3RV, `std::istringstream`, perhaps, or `boost::lexical_cast`?

Comment: @theB3RV: I've added some suggestions if you're stuck in the past. They're not pleasant though; I highly recommend moving to modern C++.

Comment: can't upgrade due to the program needing to be run on the school's system when I am finished. decided to look up the strtoll and works fine.